# Taking a pill on Yom Kippur

Tags: halacha, medicine, yom-kippur, pikuachnefesh-danger-life

What factors go into determining the permissibility of taking a pill on Yom Kippur when there is no chance the patient will die if they fail to take the pill for 25 hours?

The case here is *not* one of Safek Pikuach Nefesh, however the doctor would prefer that the pill not be skipped but he would not be prepared to say that there is any actual Pikuach Nefesh involved.

A person I was talking to insisted that the pill is too insignificant and non-food and there is no problem dry-swallowing a pill that is needed for health. I was a bit hesitant that the heter is so clear.

So what are the underlying Halachic considerations here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Halachipedia](http://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Yom_Kippur#Eating_on_Yom_Kippur) suggests:

> A person who is a Choleh SheEin Bo skana is permissible to take
>   medicine on Yom Kippur if it doesn’t have a good taste. If one needs
>   to have it with liquid one should have mouthwash.

The footnote for the above links to Rav Schachter's shiur [Halachot of Yamim Nora'im](http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/763723/Rabbi_Hershel_Schachter/Halachos_of_Yamim_Noraim).

My own opinion on the above quote - I don't recommend swallowing Listerine or the like, as that would cause more harm. I think by "mouthwash" they meant salt water or baking soda water.

Comment: Vinegar? I've always heard that water is mutar for medecine.

Comment: Thanks. I listened to the part of the shiur that they referenced. He says "a little bit of mouthwash won't kill anybody." He seems to mean Listerine or its cousins.

Comment: @DanF I believe Rabbi Belsky rules that all but the original Listerine (which he calls "brown") are not permitted for use because of their (potentially non-kosher) glycerine content - which is what also makes them tolerable.)

Comment: @DanF I'm assuming the capsule to which your referring is unflavored. That seems to be generally considered a reason for leniency. Glycerin is used as a sweetener, making it much more problematic.

Comment: @Loewian Well, unless you consider "old" fish a "flavor" (I have trouble swallowing big capsules), then, yes, that's correct. I didn't know that fact about glycerin.

Comment: @DanF The Star-K just calls it a "*hiddur*": http://www.star-k.org/kashrus/kk-mitzvos-cosmetics.htm#footnotesA . The OU is stricter: https://oukosher.org/blog/consumer-kosher/kashruth-issues-of-toothpaste/ . CRC prefers but doesn't require it to be kosher: http://www.crcweb.org/OTCMedicineReport.pdf ...

Comment: @DanF see also: http://www.kashrut.com/articles/med/

Comment: I think this comment thread veers off topic. It's past the point of usefulness by a couple of years to move it to chat, but if any other commenters want to pick up the discussion my recommendation would be to move it at that point.

Comment: Hi @SethJ - Thanks for the reminder. The best I can do is remove my own comments on this. I wouldn't even bother moving this to chat. The unrelated discussion is already discussed in at least one other M.Y. question, anyway. I recommend that you flag the comments from the others. Shana Tovah.

Comment: I was commenting for future readers/mods.