Do caffeine pouches need to be kosher
Caffeine pouches, no nicotine or tobacco.
I want to know if it has to be kosher certified if you do not ingest it.

Can you provide a link to a good, official description of a caffeine pouch, as well as summarise what it says there in your own words? Thank you, and welcome to Mi Yodeya

You mean a suppository? It's not "food" and it's not "eaten"; it should be fine. https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/64111/caffeine-pills-vs-suppositories-on-yom-kippur

Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first question. The more details, the better the community will be able to provide a good answer. Great to have you learn with us!
